# Nginx not serving javascript files

Tags: javascript, wordpress, nginx, php

I'm setting up a Wordpress blog on nginx by following this guide: [Installing Wordpress on EC2](http://theartofcode.tv/installing-wordpress-on-ec2/)

I've followed it step-by-step. The blog is up. But there's a problem. In the blog, there's no javascript. The js is not served, either by nginx or php-fpm.

Can someone please guide me. I'm really stuck bad. I don't know much of nginx or php either. :(

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance at that tutorial you should be running [this default.conf](https://github.com/ewanleith/Wordpress-Server-Configuration-Files/blob/master/default.conf).

The relevant lines for serving static files are these ones:

```
root /var/www/;
```

and

```
location / {
        # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
}
```

This means that Nginx returns a file if it is found OR loads `index.php`, passing it the URI and args. The root directive means that it only looks for files under `/var/www`. So if you have a folder at `/var/www/js` with a file inside it called `my.js` you should be able to load it by visiting `http://<your-domain>/js/my.js`.

Where are you trying to serve these js files from. What's the exact full path to them? Comment below and I'll keep editing this answer till we can figure it out.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to serve js files from the following path: /var/www/wp-content/themes/mythemename/theme-content/js/main.js

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the premium theme I'm using. I've raised a ticket with them. Looks like their custom widget is breaking things. I'll update this if the issue gets solved.

Comment: So if you visit http://<YOUR-DOMAIN>/wp-content/themes/mythemename/theme-content/js/main.js` you see the contents of main.js?